# Fabric - detect host os information through env.gateway

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, fabric

```
#!  /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from fabric.api import env, run, sudo, task
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
compute = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
# sets static project
# project = 'test1'

env.key_filename = 'google_compute_engine'
forward_agent = True

@task
# gets bastion host and sets env.gateway to be used as ssh gateway
def ag_get_bh(project):
    request = compute.instances().aggregatedList(project=project)
    response = request.execute()

    for zone, instances in response['items'].items():
        for host in instances.get("instances", []):
            if host['status'] == 'RUNNING':
                if 'bh' in host['name']:
                    env.gateway = host['networkInterfaces'][0]['accessConfigs'][0]['natIP']
            else:
                print('No bastion host found')

@task
# gets running hosts in a single project across all zones
def ag_get_host(project):
    request = compute.instances().aggregatedList(project=project)
    response = request.execute()

    env.hosts = []
    for zone, instances in response['items'].items():
        for host in instances.get("instances", []):
            if host['status'] == 'RUNNING':
                env.hosts.append(host['name'])

@task
# identifies OS platform to be used in sec_update()
def get_platform():
    x = sudo("python -c 'import platform; print(platform.platform())'")
    if x.failed:
        raise Exception("Python not installed")
    else:
        return x
    print(x)

@task
# runs security updates
def sec_update():
    if 'redhat' or 'centos' in get_platform().lower():
        sudo('echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches')
        sudo('yum -y --disablerepo=rhui* install google-rhui-client-rhel7')
        sudo('yum update yum -y')
        sudo('yum update-minimal --security -y')
    elif 'ubuntu' or 'debian' in get_platform().lower():
        sudo('apt-get install unattended-upgrades')
        sudo('unattended-upgrades –v')
```

The above code gets the bastion host which is my `env.gateway`, then it gets hosts from GCP API and sets `env.hosts`, it then checks the host OS and then applies security updates.

Only when running the script through an ssh proxy (`env.gateway`) `get_platform()` never runs and thus the if statement in sec_updates never executes so my OS specific logic never executes. When running locally, (not using `env.gateway`) `get_platform()` executes properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No entirely sure what was going on here, but I ended up copying and pasting the script from another backup file that was working and the code properly executes. If anyone is interested, below is the working script:

```
#!  /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from fabric.api import env, run, sudo, task
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
compute = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# set to path of private key
env.key_filename = 'google_compute_engine'
forward_agent = True


@task
# gets bastion host and sets env.gateway to be used as ssh gateway
def ag_get_bh(project):
    request = compute.instances().aggregatedList(project=project)
    response = request.execute()

    for zone, instances in response['items'].items():
        for host in instances.get("instances", []):
            if host['status'] == 'RUNNING':
                if 'bh' in host['name']:
                    env.gateway = host['networkInterfaces'][0]['accessConfigs'][0]['natIP']
            else:
                print('No bastion host found')


@task
# gets running hosts in a single project across all zones
def ag_get_host(project):
    request = compute.instances().aggregatedList(project=project)
    response = request.execute()

    env.hosts = []
    for zone, instances in response['items'].items():
        for host in instances.get("instances", []):
            if host['status'] == 'RUNNING':
                env.hosts.append(host['name'])


@task
# gets uptime
def uptime():
    run('uptime')


@task
# gets disk space
def disk_space():
    run('df -h')


# gets OS platform to be used in sec_update()
def get_platform():
    x = sudo("python -c 'import platform; print(platform.platform())'")
    if x.failed:
        raise Exception("Python not installed")
    else:
        return x

@task
# runs OS security updates
def sec_update():
    if 'redhat' in get_platform().lower():
        sudo('echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches')
        sudo('yum -y --disablerepo=rhui* install google-rhui-client-rhel7')
        sudo('yum update yum -y')
        sudo('yum update-minimal --security -y')
    elif 'centos' in get_platform().lower():
        sudo('echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches')
        sudo('yum update yum -y')
        sudo('yum update-minimal --security -y')
    elif 'ubuntu' or 'debian' in get_platform().lower():
        sudo('apt-get install unattended-upgrades')
        sudo('unattended-upgrades -v')
    else:
        print("No supported OS found")
```